# how to stop thread inside this thread c++/cli

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I've a thread which starts on Form load:

```
            myThread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( this, &Form1::ThreadFunction1 ) );
            myThread->Start();
```

In this new thread i need to stop it inside one of this thread function:

```
public ref class MyThreadClass
{
 private:
Form1^ myFormControl1;

public:

void Run()
{
... //some operations
            Thread::Suspend();
}
};
```

But i've get a compiler error: 'class::function' : illegal call of non-static member function. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What thread library are you using?

Comment: using namespace System::Threading;

Comment: Suspend() is an instance method, not a static method.  You cannot use it anymore, it was declared [Obsolete] because many programmers used it wrong.  Like you are doing, suspending a thread is very likely to cause deadlock.  Use a proper synchronization object instead.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend()` would do what you're asking. Like others said though, using it is asking for trouble - what exactly are you trying to accomplish? It you want to "stop" the thread as in terminate it, Suspend is not the solution: just return from the function. If you need to wait for some event, follow @HansPassant advice and use some other synchronization mechanism.